# Add a command keymap ATOM

Tags: atom-editor, keymapping

I would like to add a command in the ATOM keymap.

ALT+j : Select all occurences

But I don't know how it's working, I've just add cmd+d, easily.

This is what I have right now :

```
'body':
  'cmd-,': 'application:show-settings'
  'cmd-N': 'application:new-window'
  'cmd-W': 'window:close'
  'cmd-o': 'application:open'
  'cmd-T': 'pane:reopen-closed-item'
  'cmd-n': 'application:new-file'
  'cmd-s': 'core:save'
  'cmd-S': 'core:save-as'
  'cmd-alt-s': 'window:save-all'
  'cmd-w': 'core:close'
  'cmd-ctrl-f': 'window:toggle-full-screen'
  'cmd-z': 'core:undo'
  'cmd-y': 'core:redo'
  'cmd-x': 'core:cut'
  'cmd-c': 'core:copy'
  'cmd-v': 'core:paste'
  'shift-up': 'core:select-up'
  'shift-down': 'core:select-down'
  'shift-left': 'core:select-left'
  'shift-right': 'core:select-right'
  'shift-pageup': 'core:select-page-up'
  'shift-pagedown': 'core:select-page-down'
  'delete': 'core:delete'
  'shift-delete': 'core:delete'
  'pageup': 'core:page-up'
  'pagedown': 'core:page-down'
  'backspace': 'core:backspace'
  'shift-backspace': 'core:backspace'
  'cmd-up': 'core:move-to-top'
  'cmd-down': 'core:move-to-bottom'
  'cmd-shift-up': 'core:select-to-top'
  'cmd-shift-down': 'core:select-to-bottom'
  'cmd-{': 'pane:show-previous-item'
  'cmd-}': 'pane:show-next-item'
  'cmd-alt-left': 'pane:show-previous-item'

'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'cmd-d': 'editor:duplicate-lines'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found in my keymap.cson file directed by the Atom->Settings->Keybindings tab/page:

```
# Your keymap
#
# Atom keymaps work similarly to style sheets. Just as style sheets use
# selectors to apply styles to elements, Atom keymaps use selectors to associate
# keystrokes with events in specific contexts. Unlike style sheets however,
# each selector can only be declared once.
#
# You can create a new keybinding in this file by typing "key" and then hitting
# tab.
#
# Here's an example taken from Atom's built-in keymap:
#
# 'atom-text-editor':
#   'enter': 'editor:newline'
#
# 'atom-workspace':
#   'ctrl-shift-p': 'core:move-up'
#   'ctrl-p': 'core:move-down'
#
# You can find more information about keymaps in these guides:
# * http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#_customizing_keybindings
# * http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/
#
# If you're having trouble with your keybindings not working, try the
# Keybinding Resolver: `Cmd+.` on macOS and `Ctrl+.` on other platforms. See the
# Debugging Guide for more information:
# * http://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/#check-the-keybindings
#
# This file uses CoffeeScript Object Notation (CSON).
# If you are unfamiliar with CSON, you can read more about it in the
# Atom Flight Manual:
# http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#_cson
```

The links in here are very resourceful. Check these out --

- http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#_customizing_keybindings
- http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/

For `cson` details go to **Atom flight manual**'s *basic-customization* part further.

Hope this gives you some direction on how to do it!

Comment: I already seen this links, and it doen't help me, that's why I post a subjet in StackOverflow ^^

Comment: `'.platform-darwin atom-text-editor':
  'alt-j' : 'find-and-replace:select-all'
`

Comment: @Riddick sorry about the disappointment earlier, but here is a set of lines that you can add at the end of your _keymap.cson_ file for the intended job: `'.platform-darwin atom-text-editor':
  'alt-j' : 'find-and-replace:select-all' 
`. However, there is a key-combo for the same in atom: `ctrl-cmd-g` which does the same thing and it is default. You can also verify your key-combo by pressing **`cmd-.`** first and then your intended ones.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen this command, yeah it's the same thing, I'm sorry ..